# sorting a list of names in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, alphabetical

i got a table view controller which imports a NSObject with NSStrings. in the table view controller where i create the list, is not in alphabetical order.
here is the pieces of code i am using:

Songs.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Songs : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* description;
@property (assign) int serial;

-(id) initWithName:(NSString*) SongName andDescription:(NSString*)theDescription;

@end
```

songs.m:

```
#import "Songs.h"

@implementation Songs
@synthesize name;
@synthesize description;
@synthesize serial;

-(id) initWithName:(NSString *)theName andDescription:(NSString *)theDescription
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        self.name = theName;
        self.description = theDescription;
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

and the tableview:

```
#import "TableViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "Songs.h"

@implementation TableViewController

@synthesize allTableData;
@synthesize filteredTableData;
@synthesize letters;
@synthesize searchBar;
@synthesize isFiltered;

NSArray *SongsIndexTitles;
    SongsIndexTitles = @[@"A", @"B", @"C",@"Ç", @"D", @"E", @"F", @"G", @"H", @"I",@"İ", @"J", @"K", @"L", @"M", @"N", @"O", @"Ö", @"P", @"R", @"S",@"Ş", @"T", @"U",@"Ü", @"V", @"Y", @"Z"];

    allTableData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                    [[Songs alloc] initWithName:@"Ağlarsa Anam Ağlar" andDescription:@"Seslendiren: Abidin"],
                    [[Songs alloc] initWithName:@"Aynalı Kemer" andDescription:@"Seslendiren: Abidin"],
                    [[Songs alloc] initWithName:@"Boşuna " andDescription:@"Seslendiren: Abidin"],
                    [[Songs alloc] initWithName:@"Çöpçüler " andDescription:@"Seslendiren: Abidin"],
                    [[Songs alloc] initWithName:@"Ahu Gozlum" andDescription:@"Seslendiren: Abidin"],
                    [[Songs alloc] initWithName:@"Hepsi Senin mi?" andDescription:@"Seslendiren: Abidin"],
                    [[Songs alloc] initWithName:@"Neredesin Sen?" andDescription:@"Seslendiren: Abidin"],
                    [[Songs alloc] initWithName:@"Pamuk" andDescription:@"Seslendiren: Abidin"],
                    [[Songs alloc] initWithName:@"Sen Yoluna Ben Yoluma" andDescription:@"Seslendiren: Abidin "],
                    [[Songs alloc] initWithName:@"Yolcu Yolunda Gerek" andDescription:@"Seslendiren: Abidin "],
```

and the list goes on and on. the sectioning works great but i could not figure out how to make the song names in each section in alphabetical order; like in A section it should be 1-Ahu Gozlum 2-Aglarsa Anam Aglar 3- Aynali Kemer....

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Look in the NSArray documentation for various methods with "sort" in the name.

Comment: Then look in the NSString documentation for various methods with "compare" in their name.

Comment: i have, i have tried NSArray *sortedArray = [allTableData sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]; but i think i am missing sonething

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

Use `NSSortDescriptor`.  Ensure `allTableData` is an `NSMutableArray`:

```
NSSortDescriptor *desc = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name"
                                                       ascending:YES];
[allTableData sortUsingDescriptors:@[ desc ]];
```

Then reload the tableview.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];

    NSArray* sortedArray=[allTableData sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
```

Comment: in the simulator it gives no error nor warnings but it still is not listing properly

Comment: May be you are looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it

Comment: does the allTableData have to be a NSMutableArray?

Comment: Not sure, but mine was NSMutableArray

Comment: i think that is the problem mine is not, and i think it is not possible for me to change that array to NSMutableArray.  it is driving me crazy